# Syntax for masking node

Tags: objective-c, swift, autolayout

I am trying to get a direct collision contact box around a node I have in my scene. Instead of a rectangle or a circle, I want its collision detection to be exactly around the node itself.

Apple developer manual gives this code in objective-c

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:sprite.texture size:sprite.texture.size];
```

I tried this in Swift

```
invisinode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFromPath: invisinode.size)
```

But to no avail. What would be the proper syntax so that the collision box is directly around invisinode?

Comment: Why are you using `edgeChainFromPath:` instead of `texture:size`?

Comment: I keep getting the error "GameScene.Type does not have member"

Comment: I don't think that answers my question

Comment: I suppose I just don't understand the syntax related to that way.

Comment: Is `invisinode` a `GameScene`? If so, perhaps its superclass doesn't have a `physicsBody` property?

Comment: No, invisinode is the SKSpritenode that I want to create a hitbox for. GameScene is a .swift file. I am slightly surprised it is so difficult to do this in swift, surely not all objects in spritekit are just rectangles and circles?

Comment: I don't think your problem has anything to do with Swift or SpriteKit. It sounds more like you have unbalanced brackets or some other typographical error.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be in Swift, your question is tagged as both so I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

If you want your `SKSpriteNode` the same size as the texture you're giving it, then you can set your physics body to be the same size, centered in your node:

```
var skspriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

var skspriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: skspriteTexture, size: skspriteTexture.size())
skspriteNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: skspriteNode.size.width / 2)
```

Comment: I have seen this before, but it isn't a circle. It is a piece of art I designed in illustrator that is made up of multiple rectangular shapes. I have declared my node just as let invisinode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "invisinode")

Comment: In that case you may want to look at `SKShapeNode`:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKShapeNode/lineLength which will still utilize your `texture` size for your `physicsBody`.

Comment: When I try doing it the way you suggest I get some strange error "GameScene.Type does not have a member named 'skspritetexture' "

Comment: You'll have to move your `texture` variable (or the member it cannot find) up outside of the `didMoveToView()`, into the class itself. You are not allowed to call an initialized variable from the same method.

Comment: Ok, I figured out all the syntax for it and got it to run. Unfortunately it is just rendering the hitbox of my object as a big circle and not as the texture that I described.